# Best way to store a password

Tags: java, passwords

I have a java program that scraps web pages and store data on a db.
This program has no user interface, it's run vy the linux boot sequence.
what is the best way to store the db and sites password for a program like this?

I alreasy tried pass them via configuration file or command line, but i'm not very satisfied.

Thanks

Comment: which passwords exactly, of the database connection used by the command line tool? what do you mean the sites password,

Comment: both, of the db and the sites

Answer (score 0):

You can use some secure keystore or wallet, but the bottom line is, as long as an attacker gains access to it, they can simply alter the script to print out the credentials.

Since your system consists of at least 2 components (script, db), you have to think of security on the level of the whole system. E.g. it doesn't matter if you put the cleartext passwords in the script if your system is not accessible externally by any means. On the other hand, you can have the best encryption and anti-tracing techniques, and yet, by simply setting up a proxy between your software and the DB software, one can scoop the password.

There is no simple answer for this. Sysadmins generally put the password in the script and make it 700.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excellent article that might help: [Codinghorror](http://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/)

Generally I would say: Put restrictive chmod rules & salt, salt, salt !

Answer (score 0):

Unless you deal with very sensitive data such as Banking. I would say don't worry about it.

Do your best to secure the server itself.If you don't want to expose the password in config file. Then create a class for your java program that will hold them.Then compile the code.

No matter what you do, you will still have to type in the password somewhere.